# Changing the URL of an element I cannot edit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a Content Management System that places a title on the top of all our webpages. If you click on this title, it takes you to the main homepage. This part of the page is something I cannot change, but fortunately I can add CSS and/or Javascript to these webpages.

Is there a way to make it so that clicking on that title, it takes me to a different URL? I cannot edit the HTML that is used to display that title (Posted below)

I have honestly not been able to think up of a solution for this. I can only imagine that it's possible through Javascript, but I'm not sure.

```
<h1 class="page-title">
    <span><a data-home-link="" href="/sites/ww/MyWebPage">My Web Page</a></span>
</h1>
```

I would like to be able to click on the "H1" element and have it take me to a different webpage, different from "MyWebPage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change the html to add an id you could use document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll

For example, if it's the only 'a' element with that link address on the page you can use:

```
document.querySelector('a[href="/sites/ww/MyWebPage"]').setAttribute('href', '/elsewhere/page');
```

Or if it's the 1st of >1 you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="/sites/ww/MyWebPage"]')[0].setAttribute('href', '/elsewhere/page');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I cannot edit the HTML, and I also have links to "MyWebPage" in the body, so your 2nd option was what worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give your  element a unique id and then edit its attributes with javascript. So you will have:

```
<a data-home-link="" href="/sites/ww/MyWebPage" id = "someId">
```

And then with javascript, you can change its attributes like so:

> document.getElementById('someId').setAttribute('href',
>   '/sites/someOtherFolder/..');

Answer (score 0):

Should you want to not display the enforced title at all, just use JavaScript or jQuery to hide class "page-title"

Eg with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".page-title").hide();
});
```